# disable the application menu on one qml page

Tags: qml, blackberry-cascades

How do i disable the application menu on one qml page? Currently, all qml pages have application menu, but I want to disable it in the login page. My application menu is inside the main.qml. Here's what I added to my main.qml:

```
Menu.definition: MenuDefinition {
    settingsAction: SettingsActionItem {
        imageSource: "asset:///images/navbar_icon_settings.png"

        onTriggered: {
            cppObj.onSettingsClicked();
        }
    }
```

My main.qml is the first page which is the login page, but I dont want the user to be able to swipe down and reveal the settings button

Answer (score 2):

Look at [bb::cascades::Application::setMenuEnabled(bool enabled)](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__application.html#function-setmenuenabled-enabled). I think this is what you need for your use case.